# user profile api doesn't return the authenticationMethods info [docusignapi]

Tags: docusignapi

From the eSig API, GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/profile, this will return the authenticationMethods information, but when I tried on sandbox, I didn't get that section.

the whole api url:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx/users/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx/profile
```

Response:

```
{
    "displayProfile": "true",
    "displayOrganizationInfo": "false",
    "displayPersonalInfo": "false",
    "displayUsageHistory": "false",
    "companyName": "dd",
    "title": "Z",
    "userDetails": {
        "userName": "X Y",
        "userId": "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-a2a2-79cac67194c7",
        "uri": "/users/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-a2a2-xxxxxxx",
        "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
        "createdDateTime": "2019-10-07T12:38:53.2330000Z",
        "userAddedToAccountDateTime": "0001-01-01T08:00:00.0000000Z",
        "firstName": "X",
        "lastName": "Y",
        "permissionProfileId": "xxxxxx",
        "permissionProfileName": "Account Administrator",
        "defaultAccountId": "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "address": {
        "address1": "",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "",
        "stateOrProvince": "",
        "postalCode": "",
        "phone": "",
        "fax": "",
        "country": ""
    },
    "usageHistory": {
        "signedCount": "0",
        "sentCount": "0"
    },
    "userProfileLastModifiedDate": "2019-10-07T06:08:49.1700000Z"
}
```

Comment: can you post the url you called and the json you got back?

Comment: updated, please have a look.

Comment: is this a new user? did this user authenticate to DocuSign? it's possible there's a bug of some sort, but this section should show if the user that was passed authenticated to DocuSign

Comment: Yeah, I created this account yesterday, I can login to docsign application and admin site. Is it reproducible on your end? Thanks.

Comment: I am having similar kind of issue, I am not able to get the attributes : companyname,title.